# How do I limit an iOS app only to 4 inch screen devices?

Tags: ios, xcode

Is there a setting in Xcode that lets me declare that my app only supports 4" screen devices (iPhone 5 and the newest iPod Touch)?

Comment: Why would you want that?

Comment: @omz It would simplify design, only having to worry about one screen size.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

### Nope.

Because iOS 7 supports devices with 3.5" screens, you can't use the only-support-iOS-x technique.

Also, there isn't a setting in Xcode or a key for `requiredDeviceCapabilities` which allows you to make the app 4-inch only.

Comment: You could require 64-bit devices, since the oldest 64-bit device is the iPhone 5s and iPod touch 6th generation. But that's annoying unless you have a good reason other than screen size.

Answer (score 5):

As you can see in below screenshot which is taken from Apple's official website, iPhone 4 and iPhone 4s are the ones with 3.5 inch screen and they do support iOS 7.

[image]

So you cannot constrain the app resolution support for 4 inch screen only by even using iOS 7.

Also as per the below forum there is no way we can just put application on app store that only supports 4 inch screen iPhone.

[iPhone app for 4-inch screen only?](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1610239)

Let me know if you need more help.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You may not be able to add a setting in Xcode or a key for requiredDeviceCapabilities which allows you to make the app 4-inch only. But you can allow the user launch the application first, then in the very beginning view controller detect screen size by using following code:

```
CGRect screenBound = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
CGSize screenSize = screenBound.size;
CGFloat screenWidth = screenSize.width;
CGFloat screenHeight = screenSize.height;
```

Last, based on the device screen size you preferred to run your app, you can either disable the next activity or continue.