# Is it possible to exclude 3.5 inch screen devices when submitting an iOS app?

Tags: ios

When submitting an iOS app to iTunes connect, is it possible to **exclude** 3.5" devices? I do not want to support this screen size, just 4" and above.

Comment: As a non-iOS guy I find it shocking this answer isn't readily available in the docs as in Android?

Comment: This seems to be answered in this answer: <http://stackoverflow.com/q/17903577/1562772> Basically you can only force supported iOS version but not screen size or device.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils Android devices have screens!? Then everything the Dear Leader has told us is wrong.

Comment: What I find shocking is the question, indeed. You're talking about iPhones here not Internet Explorer :-(

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils it’s not in the docs because it’s not something that’s supported. You can omit devices based on hardware requirements (lack of GPS, camera, altimeter, etc), but not arbitrary cutoffs or screen size. If this were a game, you could require Metal, which would be all A7 and above devices. But even if you’re iOS 8 only, that still includes the iPhone 4S.

Comment: @ZevEisenberg: That's interesting. I assume it's not of high priority due to the lack of endless screen sizes in comparison to [droid](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#support).

Comment: It’s actually the opposite of high priority: Apple’s customers value the fact that they can buy a phone and be guaranteed that it will run the latest software longer than most Android phones. Of course, it’s a tradeoff, and the slowest devices to support a version of iOS are sometimes pretty sluggish.

Comment: @ZevEisenberg: Yeah, that's what I said, or meant to. I can't say I'm sure about a better guarantee than android. If you're willing to put the extra effort in, it's possible to add functionality to older droids that wasn't possible when originally released. [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) is an example. I get your point though.

Comment: “If you’re willing to put the extra effort in…” Exactly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I checked the [iTunes Connect App Properties documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Appendices/Properties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH26-SW1) and the [App's Metadata](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/ChangingAppMetadata.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH3-SW19) documentation and unfortunately there doesn't look like there is an easy way to restrict your app from *not* being downloadable onto a iPhone 4S and older device.

But one thing you could try doing is setting your app to build for `armv7s` & `armv8` ([see this related question for more elaboration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22878827/restricting-app-installations-from-appstore-only-to-users-with-iphone-5-5s-5c)), or if that doesn't work, you could try throwing a "you need a modern iPhone in order to run this app" if it's launched on a smaller screen. This might be okay if your app is free, but you certainly will have an interesting time getting it onto the store if it's a paid app.

Comment: I don't think Apple would take the price tier into account - as you can always change it after approval.  I think an app that doesn't work on an iPhone 4s will be rejected

Comment: only one way to find out (i.e. submit it!)