# how to declare app is not for 3.5inch iphone4?

Tags: ios, iphone

I have an app and it is suited for iPhone over 3.5 inch, not for 3.5 inch screen size.
My app is for iPhone 5, 5s, 6, 6Plus, iPad.

I make a archive with development target for iOS 8.
The apple iTunes connect require 3.5 inch screenshot.
how to declare it's not for 3.5 inch iPhone 4?
Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to exclude 3.5 inch screen devices when submitting an iOS app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26519435/is-it-possible-to-exclude-3-5-inch-screen-devices-when-submitting-an-ios-app)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do that.The only thing you can actually adjust is the Target iOS and the device family (iPad or iPhone). If you pick iOS8 and iPhone, your app will be inevitable available for all devices which support iOS8. This includes the iPhone 4s.

Comment: Some apps are in app store read it's compatable with 5,6 etc. not says 4.

Comment: Are you sure that it says that this particular app is optimzed for iPhone 5, 6 and 6 plus? That does not mean that it is not available for iPhone 4 :)

Comment: It will say than an app is "optimised for iPhone 5/6/6+" if it supports the larger screen sizes. The omission of 4S from the list doesn't mean that the app doesn't run on the 4.