# sumbit app to AppStore only for iPhone 5/5s and iPhone 6/6+

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect

I don't want users who are using iphone 4/4s find and install my app in the app store. because the screen is too small for my app.

how to do that?

Comment: See [How do I limit an iOS app only to 4 inch screen devices?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17903577/how-do-i-limit-an-ios-app-only-to-4-inch-screen-devices)  (basically the answer is it's not possible)

Answer (score 1):

The only filtering you can do is iOS version based and not device based. So, its not possible to do so.

courtesy :- http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1610239

https://stackoverflow.com/a/17903592/1865424

https://stackoverflow.com/a/18498233/1865424