# How do I disable iphone 3.5" screen Xcode

Tags: xcode, swift, xcode6

I am trying to submit my app to the app store, but it says my build allows 3.5" in screens. I can't figure out how to disallow 3.5" screen in my build :) Any insight would be great. Been googling forever trying to find a solution, but for some reason I can't! Thank you

Comment: Hey OP, consider accepting my answer if it helped you :)

Comment: @LinusGeffarth done :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope, you can not disallow 3.5" screens. I don't know why you should do that but inside Xcode, you could check for the screen's height programmatically and if it is 480 then make a welcome screen or something where you can state that the app does not run on that device.

Also, if you don't mind waiting, I bet iOS 9 will support iPhone5+ only which eliminates the 3.5" screens.

Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you can't do that. The only filtering you can do is version based.

For further references:

1. [sumbit app to AppStore only for iPhone 5/5s and iPhone 6/6+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27298801/sumbit-app-to-appstore-only-for-iphone-5-5s-and-iphone-6-6?lq=1)
2. [How do I limit an iOS app only to 4 inch screen devices?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17903577/how-do-i-limit-an-ios-app-only-to-4-inch-screen-devices)